# Crashed: com.apple.CoreLocation in Background iOS13(only)

Tags: swift, iphone, crash, core-location, ios13

My app is crashing in background for iOS13 only.
Crash log says, it somehow connected to CoreLocation. But I am not doing any location update in background. The app works fine with the older version of iOS. Here is the crash log - [image]

Comment: Do you have the data protection entitlement set to complete?

Comment: Yes. Is it causing the issue?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think thats the issue of all my BG crashes. I will update the settings.

Comment: Hi. According to latest entries to this thread the issue should be solved with iPad/iOS 13.2 Beta 3: https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/384064#384064

Comment: I used 'Complete unless open' feature and it still crashes. I think my manager won't allow me to use the 'complete until first user auth' because of security issue. Thanks for your comment. Appreciate your time and effort. Will wait for 13.2 public release.